# Sending data to server and save as a file

Tags: javascript, servlets

```
    document.location.href = somedata
```

this link will give an image file while opening it,now want content to be sent to servlet and save as an image file. how to do it any idea?

Comment: Please be more precise (edit your question), do you want to do a HTTP GET or POST call. For the latter `document.location.href` is the wrong way.

Comment: am using canvas2image.js which will give image while calling it,but this is on client side,i need the image not to be saved in client side,i want to save file on server side,so that i could mail with attachments